# Is there a way to launch python idle via command line on ChromeOS's linux terminal?

Tags: python, python-idle, google-chrome-os

I have been searching for a way to use python on my ChromeOS laptop, I can get the `python3` command working but cannot find a way to open IDLE.

The commands that are tradiditionally used such as python -m idlelib have failed to do anything.

Please tell me if im doing something wrong.

I currently do not know how I got python on my laptop. I believe it came with it.

Comment: `The commands that are tradiditionally used` - which commands did you run? What error messages/output did you get? How did you install python

Comment: Please use the [edit] function to add this info to your question

Comment: How did you install python? What did you do to get the `python3 command working`?

Comment: Rather than IDLE, you could try Vscode and open a Python notebook file. Or use Google colab on the web and not install anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but you first have to turn on linux mode, You can find how to do that here:
https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/9145439?hl=en

Then, enter the following commands in the order they are gievn, you will have to type them in manually:

---

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install python3`

`sudo apt-get install idle-python3`

to install pip, to install librarys, use this:

`sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).